# How do I display text in a instant message type format

Tags: java, message

I have tried to find a way to print out text into a IM like format but the only info I can find is how to display it in pop-up boxes. Is there any way to display text that I entered into a text message/IM type format?

Comment: Take a look at [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "IM like format"?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. What do you mean be "IM like format"?? What is IM? Please be more clear

Comment: I mean display like in a text one message is on the screen in a bubble then if I type another it goes under the previous one and if the person on the other end sends one it is on the other side